# How to implement Angular 4 or 5 basic authentication rest calls?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am trying to access rest service from angular js without authentication. its working fine.

### without authentication

```ts
getGroupData() {
    this.getUrl = this.coreurlService.serviceURL ;
    const url = this.getUrl.fetchtpaassociations_url+this.localStorageService.get('tpaid')+'' ; 
    return this.http.get(url)
};
```

### With authentication

```ts
getGroupData(){
    this.getUrl = this.coreurlService.serviceURL ;
    const url = this.getUrl.fetchtpaassociations_url+this.localStorageService.get('tpaid')+'' ; 
    var headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic asd239asd9aslkasdASDFASDFSADF9flk34jrlsadkjfLAKSDJFAASLDKJFASLD=='               
        }
    let obs = new Observable(observer => {
        this.http.get(url, {headers: headers}).subscribe(
            (response: Response) => {
                observer.next(response);
                observer.complete();
            },
            error=> {
                observer.error(error);
            });     
    });
    return obs;
};
```

Its not working with authentication. Please help me in this.
Thanks

Comment: What are you using HTTPModule or HTTPClientModule

Comment: You can try using CanActivate interface for the same. Src: https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that your BasicAuth hash was right?

After you make sur that your call works fine with a Rest client (like Postman), maybe you should try using Angular 4 `Headers` like this :

```
getGroupData(){

    this.getUrl = this.coreurlService.serviceURL ;
    const url = this.getUrl.fetchtpaassociations_url+this.localStorageService.get('tpaid')+'' ; 

    let headers: Headers = new Headers();
    let options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    options.headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic asd239asd9aslkasdASDFASDFSADF9flk34jrlsadkjfLAKSDJFAASLDKJFASLD==');  

    return this.http.get(url, options);
};
```

I also directly returned your `http.get` result like in the previous example.